# Replacing xml Attribute with another xml attribute value SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I have a simple xml like

`<x y=1>`

what i want to do is add one more attribute Z and assign the value of y

expected result is 
`<x y="1" z="1">`

i want to do it in SQL

Thanks in advance

Comment: What SQL do you use? MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle etc? Please, specify.

Comment: Your title has "Replacing" in it, but your question itself wants to "add" another attribute. Either change the title to "Add ..." or reword your question.

Answer (score 1):

i found the ansewr

it is like

```
UPDATE dbo.tbl
       set  DataXml.modify('insert (attribute Z{/x/@Y})  into (/x)[1] ')
      where not  cast(DataXml as nvarchar(max)) like 'z=%'
```

it add attribute z if there is no attribute z and assign the value of y

Comment: You've found `.modify()` - great! -, but you should've found `.exist()` as well... Because your approach with a cast and a `LIKE` search is slow and erronous...